# If a marker is not equal to null, then how do I remove the marker and create a new one?

Tags: android, google-maps, firebase

My question seems redundant but I can't find the exact answer on my problem. I have 2 apps one is the user that sends location to Firebase and second app is getting the location from firebase and create a marker. Whenever the user changes its location  the marker doesn't update worst, the previous marker can still be seen on the map and it added another marker. How can I resolve this? To understand my problem further here is my code.

This is the 2nd app: getting the location

```
passRef = new Firebase(Config.FIREBASE_URL_PASSENGER);
        passRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                    if (snapshot.child("latitude").exists() && snapshot.child("longitude").exists() && snapshot.child("destination").exists()) {

                        passUsername = snapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
                        numOfPassenger = Integer.parseInt(snapshot.child("numberOfSeats").getValue().toString());
                        //getting the passenger's current location
                        locLatPass = Double.valueOf(snapshot.child("latitude").getValue().toString());
                        locLongPass = Double.valueOf(snapshot.child("longitude").getValue().toString());

                        dummyLocLatPass = Double.valueOf(snapshot.child("latitude").getValue().toString());
                        dummyLocLongPass = Double.valueOf(snapshot.child("longitude").getValue().toString());

                        if (locLatPass.equals("")) {
                            locLatPass = dummyLocLatPass;
                        }
                        if (locLongPass.equals("")) {
                            locLongPass = dummyLocLongPass;
                        }

                        latlngpass = new LatLng(locLatPass, locLongPass);

                        passLocMarkerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
                        passLocMarkerOptions.position(latlngpass);
                        passLocMarkerOptions.title(passUsername + "'s Location");

                        passLocMarkerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.pass_location));
                        passLocationMarker = mMap.addMarker(passLocMarkerOptions);

                    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
passLocationMarker = mMap.addMarker(passLocMarkerOptions);
```

You can do

```
if (passLocationMarker == null) {
    passLocationMarker = mMap.addMarker(passLocMarkerOptions)
} else {
    passLocationMarker.setPosition(latlngpass);
}
```

You can also set other properties such as title or icon.